# Using substring to evaluate table value one with leading zeros

Tags: sql, coldfusion, substring

I am not having any luck making this work and I am not sure what I am missing. I am new to coldfusion and SQL and still learning.

I have a binding that I am doing within a form. After a user selects a service type in needs to generate a name which is located in another table. The problem I have is that the service type is using a service number which is located in both tables. However in one table the creator added leading zeros to the number. For example one table will have 205 and the other table will have 0000205 I need to compare these to get the name value I want. Here is the coding I have so far. This is using coldfusion and java.

cfc file called servicetype2

```
<cffunction name="getServiceType2" access="remote" returnType="array">
<cfargument name="CATG_NAME" type="string" required="true">

<cfset var data="">
<cfset var result=ArrayNew(2)>
<cfset var i=0>


<cfquery name="getServiceType2" datasource="SOME DATABASE">
select 1 AS SortBy,  '' AS SRTY_NBR, '' AS SRTY_NAME
from SOME TABLE
UNION
select distinct 2 AS SortBy, SRTY_NBR, SRTY_NAME
from SOME TABLE
where CATG_NAME = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.CATG_NAME#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> AND EVLN_REQD_FLAG IS NOT NULL
order by SortBy
</cfquery>

<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#getServiceType2.recordcount#">
<cfset result[i][1]=getServiceType2.SRTY_NAME[i]>
<cfset result[i][2]=getServiceType2.SRTY_NAME[i]>
</cfloop>

<cfreturn result>
</cffunction>

 //Table 2
<cffunction name="getUnion" access="remote" returnType="array">
<cfargument name="SRTY_NBR" type="string" required="true">


<cfset var result=ArrayNew(1)>

<cfquery name="union_rq" datasource="SOME DATABASE">
select UNI_NAME, substring(SRTY_NBR, patindex('%[^0]%',SRTY_NBR),10)
from SOME TABLE
where substring(SRTY_NBR, patindex('%[^0]%',SRTY_NBR),10)
     = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.SRTY_NBR#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> 
 </cfquery>

 <cfset result[1]=union_rq.UNI_NAME>

 <cfreturn result>
 </cffunction>
```

The code which is in my form is:

```
     <tr id="serv_ty2" style="display: inline;">
<td></td>
<td>Select Service:
     <cfselect name="service_type"
     bind="cfc:servicetype2.getServiceType2({catdesc})"
bindonload="false"/></td>
</tr>


     <tr id="union" style="display: inline;">
<td></td>
<td>Union Attached:
<cfinput name="uni_name"
     bind="cfc:servicetype2.getUnion({service_type})"
bindonload="false"
/></td>
</tr>
```

Again the binding is working fine but I can not get the name to come up and I am sure it has to do with my SQL statement comparing the 205 to 0000205. Any advice on how you would make the sql statement work would be great. If you notice any other errors with the binding that would be great as well. 
Thank you in advance for any advice you can provide.

Comment: The answer below is a good solution.  However, it's also a good time to point out that if the data type was properly set then 0000205, 00205, 205 would all match 205 and vice versa.  In MySQL, it's also half the storage cost.  Using a medium int is 4 bytes per row, varchar(7) at 1 byte per char (could be more) uses double that at 8 bytes per row, 1 byte for ea char (7 total) and 1 byte to record the length.  Starts adding up real quick and it's all for a bunch of zero's.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NumberFormat()` in your Query

```
WHERE srty_nbr IN (<cfqueryparam    
    value="#ARGUMENTS.SRTY_NBR#,#NumberFormat(ARGUMENTS.SRTY_NBR,'0000000')#" 
    cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true">
```

`#NumberFormat(ARGUMENTS.SRTY_NBR,'0000000')#` will make sure every number has 7 digits with leading zeros.

Comment: Not sure about this.  If arguments.srty_nbr is a list of numbers, like 1,2,3 then numberformat might not do what you hope for.  On the other hand, if it's a single number, then = is better than in ().

Comment: @DanBracuk he said it's one number and the IN is because it's checking for 205 and 0000205.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is casting the value on SQL level. This is easily done by altering the selection of the column to: `SELECT ..., CAST(SRTY_NBR AS UNSIGNED) ...` This will truncate leading zeros.

Comment: I would absolutely agree with this. Unless there is a reason to carry over the leading zeros into your query output, let the SQL server do the job it was made for. The SQL server is usually much better at manipulating data like this. Let it CAST the data as an int and the comparison is MUCH easier and more efficient. Personally, unless there is a very good reason for storing the data that way, I'd say it's poor database design.